# router.delete returns empty array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to add a function that deletes a record in MongoDB by the id, but I'm getting an empty array as a result and the record is not deleted.

Here is my code so far:

```
//router
router.delete('/comandas/:id', (req, res) => {
  deleteLine(req.params.id)
  res.status(500).end()
  });
});
```

```
//delete function
const objectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

const init = () =>
  MongoClient.connect(connectionUrl, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }).then((client) => {
    db = client.db(dbName)
  })

const deleteLine = (id) => {
  const collection = db.collection('comanda')
  return collection.deleteOne({"_id": objectId(id)})
}
```

Comment: You are using mongoose for schema, but you are connecting to the db and deleting with native mongodb package. Why?

Comment: @SuleymanSah I'm using the model for other methods too. How can that affect in this?

Comment: Ok then it is unnecessary to include mongoose schema code to the question. Also it is not a good idea to use both mongodb and mongoose packages in the same app.

Comment: I'll edit the question and check the rest of the code regarding this. What about the delete function not working?

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a promise in deleteLine function,  in your router to actually make it run you need to add then block like this:

```js
  deleteLine(req.params.id).then(result => {
    console.log(result);    
    //todo: send response
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
      //todo: send error response
  })
```

Comment: This didn't work but I've solved it another way in the answer below

Comment: @PabloG this is the same code as in your answer? What do you mean this didn't work?

Comment: @PabloG please consider accepting this answer, this solves your question.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to solve this calling the get methods instead:

```html
router.get('/comandas/:id/delete', (req, res) => {
   deleteLine(req.params.id)
  .then( () => {
    console.log(req.params.id + ' deleted')
    res.status(500).end()
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
    res.status(500).end()
  });
});
```